# Directive causing $scope to go undefined when it fires off

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, angular-meteor

Today I tried my hand at writing a directive in angular purely for means to make my own "check if this email exists" validation.

However, when the directive runs, it clears out the scope - rendering it undefined and I have no cooking-clue why. disabling the directive causes my scope not to go lost when I try to submit my form. Can anyone Explain to me why it would do this?

my html:

```
<form class='form-horizontal' name="userForm" novalidate>
    <div class='form-group' ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.emailAddress.$invalid && !userForm.emailAddress.$pristine }">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <label class="control-label" for='emailAddress'>Email Address: </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <input class='form-control' type='email' id='emailAddress' name='emailAddress' ng-model='letMeKnowEmail' email-exists required/>
          <p ng-show="userForm.emailAddress.$error.required && !userForm.emailAddress.$pristine" class=".input-error">Your email is required.</p>
          <p ng-show="userForm.emailAddress.$error.email && !userForm.emailAddress.$pristine" class=".input-error">Your email is in an invalid format.</p>
          <p ng-show="userForm.emailAddress.$error.emailExists && !userForm.emailAddress.$pristine" class=".input-error">This email already exists.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <button class='btn btn-theme' ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid" ng-click='userForm.$invalid || addEmail(letMeKnowEmail)'>Let Me Know!</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

my angular JS file:

```
/* dependancies */
import angular from 'angular';
import angularMeteor from 'angular-meteor';
import uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';

/* templates */
import template from './applicationProcessTemp.html';

class ApplicationProcessTempCtrl {
  constructor($scope, $reactive) {
    $reactive(this).attach($scope);
    $scope.letMeKnowEmail = '';
    $scope.addEmail = function(letMeKnowEmail) {
      if (this.userForm.$valid) {
        SiteInterestShown.insert({
          email: letMeKnowEmail
        });
      }
    }
  }
}

const name = 'applicationProcessTemp';
ApplicationProcessTempCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$reactive'];

export default angular.module(name, [
    angularMeteor
  ]).component(name, {
    template,
    controllerAs: name,
      controller: ApplicationProcessTempCtrl
  }).config(config)
  .directive('emailExists', directive);

function config($stateProvider) {
  'ngInject';

  $stateProvider.state('applicationTemp', {
    url: '/applicationTemp',
    template: '<application-process-temp></application-process-temp>'
  });
}

config.$inject = ['$stateProvider'];

function directive($timeout, $q) {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attr, model) {
      model.$asyncValidators.emailExists = function() {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        $timeout(function() {
          var exists = SiteInterestShown.findOne({
            'email': model.$viewValue
          }) == undefined;
          model.$setValidity('emailExists', exists);
          defer.resolve;
        }, 1);
        return defer.promise;
      }
    }
  }
}

directive.$inject = ['$timeout', '$q'];
```

The environment is a meteor environment, however I have severe doubts that meteor is causing my scope to go undefined **at the point the directive fires off to validate whether or not the email exists**. I have my suspicions that minimongo might be involved in this matter (`SiteInterestShown` variable is a mongo collection set in the collections folder on the root of the project)

Comment: the only variable I see that I remotely touch within the directive is model.$viewValue - could accessing this cause the $scope to go undefined once the button is clicked and the $scope.addEmail() function gets kicked off( and why would the function kick off if $scope is SUPPOSED to be undefined. I'm sitting with more questions now)

Answer (score 0):

```
model.$asyncValidators.emailExists = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var value = modelValue || viewValue;

        var checkVal = model.$viewValue;
        var exists = SiteInterestShown.findOne({
          'email': value
        }) != undefined;

        if (!exists) {
          deferred.resolve(); <-- resolve was a method. called it as a method on validation success.
        } else {
          deferred.reject();  <-- reject would destroy the binding value and as far as I see, it gets auto-called if resolve() isn't fired.
        }

        return deferred.promise;
}
```

The issue that this code segment faced was that I called `resolve` as a property, not as a method. I also removed some extra code (the $timeout) as I deemed it unnecessary - but not incorrect - in this sample. the moment I called resolve(), when the deferral's promise was returned, angular did not scrap the value from my $scope - which was another thing I misunderstood. the `"$scope"` that was destroyed wasn't the entire scope, but only the **Scope variable bound to the element as it's model** because `resolve()` wasn't called - and theory here, it auto called `reject()` which scrapped the value.

Long story short - I have access to my scope variable again :)